# How can i use Math.pow in a jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to do something along the lines of,

```
<c:forEach begin = "1" end = "${obj.value}" var="i">
  Math.pow(5,${i});
</c:forEach>
```

i is a variable. This is on a jsp page. I have tried using `<% %>` as well as `<%= %>` but it is being really picky. I need to raise 5 to the power of the variable of the loop, the iterator, basically i. so on the first pass `5^1`, the second pass `5^2`, so on and so forth.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely you can do that. What stopping you ? But the syntax is not correct it seems

Comment: I apologize, I am using <c:forEach>, it slipped my mind. @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is already java code you need not to write $

```
<c:ForEach begin = "0" end = "5" var = i>
  <span> ${Math.pow(5,i)};</span>
 </c:ForEach>
```

If you want to round the value intead of decimal points

```
Math.round(Math.pow(5,2));
```

Comment: It just puts "<span> Math.pow(5,i);</span>" and doesn't compute it

Comment: Insert a semicolon `${Math.pow(5,i)};`

Comment: @SURESH Works Great, any way to make it into a int instead of a decimal?

Comment: @Renuz Yup. Edited my post.